# What works and does not work about our reputation system?

Tags: discussion

This is a current question on meta.

[The Stack Exchange reputation system: What's working? What's not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387356/the-stack-exchange-reputation-system-whats-working-whats-not)

My answer: in addition to issues of it not helping broaden our cultural reach, it does not help new users feel welcomed. There should be a floor of zero points for all questions by newbies. (If you disagree, follow the link and say so rather than discussing it here)

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387366/301090

More broadly it doesn't answer all the needs of non-technical sites. Go over there and share your views on the subject, or it never will.

Comment: Whoboy that meta q is the single largest cornucopia of horrible ideas I've ever seen (and I watch both US party conventions every 4 years).

Comment: Wow. Between that and being a mod here, you must really hate yourself.

Comment: Note - that reaction is why you should stand up and contribute - to at least two of those 3 things. Even if the contribution is downvoting bad ideas/physically throwing things at stupid people. Bring a lot of things.

Comment: I've posted some comments (and the lesser-voted answers don't tend to be as bad), but the sheer level of wrong in there is rather daunting.

Comment: hahaha. Last time I talked like T.E.D. in his poetry, the psychiatrist told me that I had a problem.

Comment: ??? If he is a poet, I did not know it